# Как сделать конструкцию, которая будет делать replace преобразование на постоянной основе элементов общего класса? (+скрин)

Tags: javascript, replace

[image: Две строки, которые преобразовывают два одинаковых элемента по ID]

Как мне сделать конструкцию, которая будет выполнять данную задачу без написания этих строк каждый раз на каждый id?

Этот код для того, чтобы выделять букву в логотипе. Логотипы будут на каждой странице и для всех нужно сделать подобную вещь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Ниже Данил написал ровно такой код, над которым я ломал голову целый день) Если у Вас ещё остался интерес по-поводу моего вопроса, то ответ можно увидеть ниже - я это спрашивал ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".logo-letter").forEach(e => e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace('o', '<span>o</span>'));
```

```html
<div class="logo-letter">oabcd</div>
<div class="logo-letter">oabcd</div>
<div class="logo-letter">oabcd</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, мил человек!

Comment: @Hedonist Если ответ помог, то отметьте его как решение :)